# Scikit_learn precision and recall computed incorectly

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, precision-recall

I have unbelievably stupid problem. Calculating precision and recall by sci-kit learn gives me crazy values, totally different than calculated by me, using confusion matrix.
Here's my code:
[image: This code should calculate all basic metrics from sklearn.metrics]

I tries also average 'weighted' and 'macro', and separated functions f_score, precision_score and recall_score. Nothing helped.
I got these results:
[image: Firstly there is y_test values, then y_pred, then recall and precision calculated out of confussion matrix results. In the end there are precision and recall calculated by sklearn b]

Firstly there is y_test values, then y_pred (as you can see, there is only one true positive prediction) then recall and precision calculated out of confusion matrix results (precision 0.14 is something I did expected). In the end there are precision and recall calculated by sklearn function and... I don't understand! Why the difference?!

Does anyone have idea why these results look like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that was veeery stupid problem. The solution was changing average='micro' to 'binary'. Then the results are correct.